# Why this GUI counter can't display after 9?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I wrote this code and it works fine from 1 to 9 but after 9 instead of displaying numbers it displays ...
Can anyone tell me what could be the problem as am I quite new to GUI.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {
    private int count = 0;
private JLabel label;
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
public GUI(){
     frame = new JFrame();
     panel = new JPanel();
     JButton button = new JButton("Start");
button.addActionListener(this);
label = new JLabel("Number of Clicks: 0");
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100,100,100,100));
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
panel.add(button);
panel.add(label);
frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setTitle("Clicker");
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GUI();

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    count++;
    label.setText("Number of Clicks: "+count);

}
```

}

Comment: It can, the problem is, there's not enough space left to do so.  When you `pack` the window, you're reducing it to the "preferred size" of the components at that moment in time.  This then assumes a single digit for the counter, once it exceeds that limit, there is no longer any more space to show it

Comment: A trick that "might" work, is to wrap the text in `<html></html>` tags, this will allow it to support multiple lines, for example `label.setText("<html>Number of Clicks: " + count + "</html>");`, but this might not produce a desirable result.

Comment: Another trick might be to use a `JTextField` to display the counter, but limit it's character width to something like `3` and then remove the decorations to make it look like a label.  This, however, will require to use a different layout manager

Comment: Or just use `"Number of Clicks:    0"` as starting value. You may also use `label.setText(String.format("Number of Clicks:%4d", count));` for updates, to get a consistent result.